# Reactjs Menu bar not working on mobile view

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have deployed a test version of my website, it works on desktop browser but opening the same site on your mobile, the menu bar does not expand. Try this link [dev site link](https://gleaming-fairy-55538c.netlify.app/)  on your computer then on a browser on your phone

Can you  have a look at my menu bar code

```
function Topbar(){
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <div className="site-header-wrapper">
        {/* <!-- Site Header --> */}
        <header className="site-header">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="site-logo">
                    <a href="/" className="default-logo"><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
                    <a href="/" className="default-retina-logo"><img src="assets/images/logo@2x.png" alt="Logo" width="199" height="30"/></a>
                    <a href="/" className="sticky-logo"><img src="assets/images/sticky-logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
                    <a href="/" className="sticky-retina-logo"><img src="assets/images/sticky-logo@2x.png" alt="Logo" width="199" height="30"/></a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" className="visible-sm visible-xs" id="menu-toggle"><i className="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <ul className="sf-menu dd-menu pull-right" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    <li><a href="/about">The Team</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/rota">Sunday Team Distribution</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/mediabooking">Book Media Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/abscences">Team Member Absences</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/skillsmatrix">Team Skills Matrix</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/events">Evencfts</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/onboarding">Training and Onboarding</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/readinesscheck">Production Readiness Check</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Admins Panel</a>
                        <ul className="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Manage Users</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog-grid.html">Manage Events</a></li>
                            <li><a href="single-post.html">Team Distribution</a></li>
                            <li><a href="single-post.html">Production Checklist</a></li>
                            <li><a href="single-post.html">Prompt Presenters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="single-post.html">Broadcast Email</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li className="megamenu"><a href="javascrip:void(0)">Mega Menu</a>
                        <ul className="dropdown">
                            <li>
                                <div className="megamenu-container container">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-md-3 megamenu-col">
                                            <span className="megamenu-sub-title"><i className="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Features</span>
                                            <ul className="sub-menu">
                                                <li><a href="shortcodes.html">Shortcodes</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="privacy-policy.html">Privacy policy</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="payment-terms.html">Payment terms</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="refund-policy.html">Refund policy</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-3 megamenu-col">
                                            <span className="megamenu-sub-title"><i className="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> Latest news</span>
                                            <div className="widget recent_posts">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="single-post.html" className="media-box">
                                                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER" alt=""/>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <h5><a href="single-post.html">A single person can change million lives</a></h5>
                                                        <span className="meta-data grid-item-meta">Posted on 11th Dec, 2015</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="single-post.html" className="media-box">
                                                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER" alt=""/>
                                                        </a>
                                                        <h5><a href="single-post.html">Donate your woolens this winter</a></h5>
                                                        <span className="meta-data grid-item-meta">Posted on 11th Dec, 2015</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-3 megamenu-col">
                                            <span className="megamenu-sub-title"><i className="fa fa-microphone"></i> Latest causes</span>
                                            <ul className="widget_recent_causes">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#" className="cause-thumb">
                                                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER" alt="" className="img-thumbnail"/>
                                                        <div className="cProgress" data-complete="88" data-color="42b8d4">
                                                            <strong></strong>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <h5><a href="single-cause.html">Help small shopkeepers of Sunyani</a></h5>
                                                    <span className="meta-data">10 days left to achieve</span>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#" className="cause-thumb">
                                                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=IMAGE+PLACEHOLDER" alt="" className="img-thumbnail"/>
                                                        <div className="cProgress" data-complete="75" data-color="42b8d4">
                                                            <strong></strong>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <h5><a href="single-cause.html">Save tigers from poachers</a></h5>
                                                    <span className="meta-data">32 days left to achieve</span>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-md-3 megamenu-col">
                                            <span className="megamenu-sub-title"><i className="fa fa-star"></i> Featured Video</span> 
                                            {/* <div className="fw-video"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/62947247" width="500" height="275"></iframe></div> */}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Topbar
```

The menu bar should be accessible both on desktop and mobile